# kivy: How can I remove highlighting from all items in FileChooserListView

Tags: python, kivy

I'd like to be able to remove highlighting from all items in a kivy FileChooserListView. I see that I can remove the actual selection by setting my FileChooserListView().selection to an empty list `[]`. But this does not remove highlighting of previously selected items. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

There does not appear to be any way to do that directly, but I think this ugly hack will work:

```
class FakeEntry():
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.path = kwargs.pop('path', None)

class FakeEvent():
    def __init__(self):
        self.profile = []
        self.button = None
        self.is_double_tap = False

'''
Clear all selections in the specified FileChooser
'''
def clear_selection(file_chooser, *args):
    layout = file_chooser.layout
    if layout.VIEWNAME == 'list':
        layout.ids.treeview.deselect_node()
    fakeTouch = FakeEvent()
    for path in file_chooser.selection[:]:
        file_chooser.entry_touched(FakeEntry(path=path), fakeTouch)
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to do anything when I add it to my code. You tested it on some test code and it worked for you?

Comment: Yes, it worked for me. Do you get any error messages?

Comment: Oops, I used the above code with `FileChooserIconView`, and it worked. When I switched it to `FileChooserListView` it did not work.

Comment: I updated my answer to handle `FileChooserListView`.  It appears that you cannot select more than one entry at a time with `FilsChooserListView`, even if you specify `multiselect=True`.